# Concat Queryset Based On Condition?

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-1.11

let's say i have models like follow `Question` and `Answer`

```
class Question(models.Model):
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

#contains all the choices of questions
class Options(models.Model):
     question = models.Foreignkey(Question)

#contains question, choice choosen by user, category
class Answer(models.Model):
     question = models.Foreignkey(Question)
     option = models.ForeignKey(Option)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
```

my queryset like follow

```
questions = Question.objects.filter(category_id=1)
answers = Answer.objects.filter(category_id=1)
```

The `questions` queryset have all the questions for category and `answers` queryset have all the answers for questions per `user`. now I want to display all the questions with answers and warning messages to unanswered question, what is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
>>> answered_question = Answer.objects.filter(question__isnull = False).values('question')
>>> Question.objects.exclude(pk__in = answered_question)
```